# Lead to (the) confusion where

Tags: definite-articles, uncountable-nouns

> Don’t listen to multiple perspectives, it will eventually lead to **the** confusion where it’s hard to focus.

Does using the definite article here make sense? We generally don’t use the definite article with uncountable nouns, unless we want to specify uncountable nouns.

In the quoted sentence, we are probably talking about specific confusion (where it’s hard to focus), so I think using the definite article is fine there. But I am not sure if the word “confusion” is used in its general meaning or specific meaning. Do we need the definite article here?

Comment: That's not a particularly idiomatic use of "confusion".

Comment: @HotLicks I agree, it might not be a good framed sentence. But I couldn’t think of any other example at the moment. I am just curious to know the relationship between the definite article and uncountable nouns in such cases.

Comment: The speaker might have been thinking of "the *kind of* confusion where..."

Comment: 'Don’t listen to multiple perspectives' is an amusingly mixed metaphor, there is a best-avoided comma splice, and as Hot Licks says 'confusion' doesn't work here. // To use 'the' with an amorphous non-count noun, there probably has to be a 'the sort of Nnc where ...' construction. From the internet: << poor decision making that [might] lead to the situation where you got yourself into trouble' (the definite article licensed by the specifying postmodification).